# Google Apps Script: Ui.showSidebar() can't be called in onSelectionChange?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

```
function onSelectionChange(e){
  if (e.range.getSheet().getName() === 'products' && e.range.getNumRows() === 1 && e.range.getNumColumns() === 1 && e.range.getSheet().getRange(e.range.getA1Notation()[0] + 1).getValue() === 'image') {
    let row = e.range.getA1Notation()[1];
    if (row > 1) {
      let htmloutput = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('<b>hello</b>');
      SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(htmloutput);
    }
  }
}
```

In a Google Sheet I am trying to write a function that when a cell in "image" column is selected a sidebar is shown to display several product images.

The code above returns an error saying

> Exception: You do not have permission to call Ui.showSidebar. Required
> permissions: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.container.ui
> at onSelectionChange(Code:20:30)

However, I do have this permission included

[image]

Also, if I attach this function to a custom menu item

```
function test2(){
  let imgURL = Drive.Files.get("1g8iKGDA-iU2T2ov614mrpPJld0i93kYK").thumbnailLink;
  let html = "<img src='" + imgURL + "'/>";
  let htmlo = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(htmlo);
}
```

It will correctly show the image in the sidebar when the menu item is clicked.

So it seems that Ui.showSidebar() is not allowed to be executed inside `onSelectionChange()`. Is this true? Is there any workaround?

Comment: onSelectionChange is a simple trigger and cannot be used to perform operations that require permissions. There is no installable version of onSelectionChange that I know of.  You may have to resort to selecting a cell and starting a function from a menu and then determining the active cell.

Comment: The [Issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/109859728) regards this as "Intended behaviour". Perhaps best not to expect a change  in the near future.

Comment: Yes. thanks! I created an image button to solve this.